# How to update string into StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, string, memory, heap-memory, stringbuilder

I had read documentation about `StringBuilder` that it represents a mutable `string` of characters and allows to expand the number of characters in the string without creating new object in the memory and ***dynamically expands memory*** to accommodate the modified `string`.

I had simple C# method that generate ***Fizz*** if the number is divisible by **3**, ***Buzz*** if the number is divisible by **5** and ***FizzBuzz*** if the number is divisible by the **3** and **5**.

The method taking as int input parameter and return string. However, I am not sure If I can use `StringBuilder` instead.

For that reason I am looking some kind help that How to update string into `StringBuilder`?

Here is the complete code of the method.

```
public static string GetValue(int input)
{
    string output = string.Empty;
    if (input % 3 == 0)
    {
        output += "Fizz";
    }

    if(input % 5 == 0)
    {
        output += "Buzz";
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(output))
    {
        output = input.ToString();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated. Thanks
Also I am looking tests must be passed.

Comment: Does knowing how to use a StringBuilder really have anything to do with FizzBuzz?  I mean, did you read the [StringBuilder documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8)?

Answer (score 1):

Stringbuilder Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8). Usage is fairly straightforward.

First, declare a new instance

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
```

Then, append text as needed

```
builder.Append("I am adding this text");
```

Get the full text output when needed

```
Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetValue(int input)
{
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    if (input % 3 == 0)
    {
        output.Append("Fizz");
    }

    if(input % 5 == 0)
    {
        output.Append("Buzz");
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```